# I am currently creating a calculator in Python and when I execute code, the buttons are in the wrong place

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I am using Tkinter to make a graphical calculator in Python. My aim is to make my calculator look similar to this - http://prntscr.com/k6exeu

I am currently still building my calculator so there's a lot of stuff missing, but I decided to do the design first. When I execute my code, I get this - http://prntscr.com/k6eyhm

I need help fixing this. I'll paste the code so far so you can spot any errors.

```
import sys

try:
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkMessageBox

except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import messagebox

window = Tk()
window.title("PyCalc")
window.geometry("500x500")

user_output = Entry(width=50, state='readonly', justify=CENTER)
zero = Button(text="0", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
one = Button(text="1", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
two = Button(text="2", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
three = Button(text="3", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
four = Button(text="4", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
five = Button(text="5", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
six = Button(text="6", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
seven = Button(text="7", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
eight = Button(text="8", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)
nine = Button(text="9", height=3, width=3, justify=LEFT)

user_output.grid(row=0)
zero.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
one.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
two.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
three.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
four.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
five.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
six.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
seven.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
eight.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
nine.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)

window.mainloop()
```

If someone would help me, I'd be very happy :)

-CodeExecution

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Have you tried simply adjusting which rows and columns to place objects in? Have you tried experimenting with other options such as `columnspan`?

Comment: `user_output` is in row 0 (explicitly), column 0 (by default).  All of your buttons have row numbers greater than 0, so they are necessarily below the Entry.  All of your buttons have column numbers greater than 0, so they are necessarily to the right of the Entry.

Comment: I need help with adjusting the entry box so it does not shove all of the buttons to the right hand side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the layout you want, your entry `user_output` has to span all buttons columns. This can be achieved with the `columnspan` grid option:

```
user_output.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
```

Moreover, you didn't specified the column in `user_output.grid` so by default it is put in column 0 while your leftmost buttons are in column 1.

```
user_output.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
zero.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
one.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
two.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
three.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
four.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
five.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
six.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
seven.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)
eight.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=N+S+E+W)
nine.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
```

gives

[image: screenshot]